# Percent of total clusters per cluster per season using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, series

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qleLb.png) with 12 clusters in total. Certain clusters don't appear in a certain season.

I want to create a multi-line graph over the seasons of the percent of a specific cluster over each season. So if there are 30 teams in the 97-98 season and there are 10 teams in Cluster 1, then that value would be .33 since cluster 1 has one third of the total possible spots.

It'll look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10G2S.png)

And I want the dateset to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZma8.png), where each cluster has its own percentage of the whole number of clusters in that season by percentage. I've tried using pandas groupby method to get a bunch of lists and then use value_counts() on that but that doesn't work since looping through `df.groupby(['SEASON']) returns tuples, not a Series.`.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.groupby` combined with `.value_counts` and `.unstack`:

```py
temp_df = df.groupby(['SEASON'])['Cluster'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().fillna(0.0)
temp_df.plot()
print(temp_df.round(2))

Cluster   0     1     2     4     5    6     7     10    11
SEASON                                                     
1996-97  0.1  0.21  0.17  0.21  0.07  0.1  0.03  0.07  0.03
1997-98  0.2  0.00  0.20  0.20  0.00  0.0  0.20  0.20  0.00
```

[image]